# how to use web service web part to display external data with kentico 11

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I currently use Kentico 11.

My site is based on Azure and I want to get some data from external database. I built a web service (.asmx) and want to use the **Repeater for web service** web part to display the result returned by my service. But I don't know how to use transformation to render the result. would you please help if you have related experience?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a [similar question](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/web-service-data-source). It may help you with loading the data.

As for the transformation - it depends whether you want to use ascx/text transformation type.

[ASCX transformations](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations/reference-transformation-methods) have this format: <%# Eval("column-name") %>
[Text transformations](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations) have this format: `{% DataItem["column-name"] %}`